# How to define HTML classes in PHP conditional statements

Tags: php, html

Here I am trying to define HTML classes inside PHP `if else` statements. For example:

```
<?php if (condition 1) { ?>
<span class = 'class1'>Line 1</span>

<?php } else if (condition 2) { ?>
<span class = 'class2'>Line 2</span>

<?php } else { ?>
<span class = 'class3'>Line 3</span>

<?php } ?>
```

Then I can apply custom changes to different classes. Thanks for comments the error is because of syntax errors. However, using this style will not help me hide those warning info before any users' input. For example, if condition 1 is `$_POST['name'] == NULL`, which meant to remind users to input their names but by default `$_POST['name']` is null. This is where I try the second style:

```
<span class = "<?= condition 1 ? "class 2": "class 1";?>">Some lines</span
```

but do not know how to add multiple conditions. For example, sometimes users' input is accepted but not in the desired format. Then I need to check if the input exists and whether or not is in the desired format. Hints to either one of my attempts will be helpful.

Comment: First code is fine second your adding the class1 before condition if thats the mistake. im trying to say depends on your needs but this will be way more easy with javascript. We need more information

Comment: This is part of some PHP exercises. Part 1 is an obvious way but as far as I know I can only include one condition if I want to use the second style. I wonder if I can do something similar using the second style (which may syntax mistakes coz I do not know if I can do this). My purpose is to define ```class1 = 'class 1'``` in one situation and define ```class1 = 'class 2'```in the other. Hopefully this can be done using only PHP.

Comment: Just don't use PHP for that. You are trying to validate form on input so use JS with jquery, it's pretty straigtforward

Comment: @Undry OK. I will then need to start learning JS ...

Comment: @SanaeKochiya yeah, I think it would be the best solution, just for your understanding:

1) PHP works when you send smth to server, it does there smth, and returns to browser.
2) As soon as HTML is inside browser PHP stops working
3) So in order to do anything with the page inside the browser already you need JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont get it but u mix them as much as u like.

```
if (condition 1 and condition 2 and !condition 3) {
      //do something
} else if ((condition 1 or condition 2) and !condition 3) {
    if (condition 1) {
        //do something
    }
    if (condition 2) {
        //do something
    }
} else if (condition 3 and !condition 1 and !condition 2) {
    //do something
} else if (condition 3 and condition 1) {
    //do something
} else if (condition 3 and condition 2) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something
}
```

but u need to be carefull some condition can be true before code gets to them.

Here is a simple edit user checks

```
$id = $data->user;
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pass = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lozinka', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$activeStatus = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'activeStatus', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$klient_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'klient_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($klient_id)) {
    echo '<span class="alert alert-danger child">' . lg_fill_all_fields . '</span></div>';
} elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo '<span class="alert alert-danger child">' . lg_invalid_email . '</span></div>';
} elseif (strlen($username) < 5) {
    echo '<span class="alert alert-danger child">' . lg_minimum_5_characters_for_username . '</span></div>';
} elseif (strlen($klient_id) != 5) {
    echo '<span class="alert alert-danger child">' . lg_5_characters_for_client_id . '</span></div>';
} elseif (empty($pass)) {
    $query = 'UPDATE wLogin_users SET klient_id = "' . $klient_id . '", active = "' . $activeStatus . '", username = "' . $username . '", email = "' . $email . '" WHERE id = "' . $id . '"';
    $data->editUser($query);
    echo '<span class="alert alert-success child" id="msg" data-id="99">' . lg_changed_successfully . '</span>';
} elseif (!empty($pass)) {
    if (strlen($pass) < 7) {
        echo '<span class="alert alert-danger child">' . lg_minimum_8_characters_for_password . '</span>';
    } elseif (strlen($pass) > 26) {
        echo '<span class="alert alert-danger child">' . lg_maximum_25_characters_for_password . '</span>';
    } else {
        $password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $query = 'UPDATE wLogin_users SET klient_id = "' . $klient_id . '", active = "' . $activeStatus . '",  username = "' . $username . '", email = "' . $email . '", password = "' . $password . '" WHERE id = "' . $id . '"';
        $data->editUser($query);
        echo '<span class="alert alert-success child" id="msg" data-id="99">' . lg_changed_successfully . '</span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this should be the right format. I should add to the post that I want to also hide those warnings info before any users' input. In my original attempt I cannot. For instance, when condition 1 is ```$_POST['name'] == NULL```, then before users' input the warning info will show up.

Comment: ive added a simple example.

Comment: Thank you! Definitely a perfect example.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code block is missing a closing brace

```
<?php if (condition 1) { ?>
<span class = 'class1'>Line 1</span>

<?php } else if (condition 2) { ?>
<span class = 'class2'>Line 2</span>

<?php } else { ?>
<span class = 'class3'>Line 3</span>

<?php }       // Add this
```

See https://3v4l.org/uXv8H

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I should add to the post that I cannot hide those warnings info before users' input. For instance, if condition 1 is ```$_POST['name'] == NULL``` and by default ```$_POST['name']``` is ```NULL```.